# Using a logger with vhosts with a node webapp

Tags: linux, node.js, logging, vhosts

I have some low traffic sites and I'm trying to set up an easy way to convert standalone node apps into something that can be `require()`d by a main app that uses `vhost` to serve many domains on a single machine. This is useful because if I don't have to hack it too bad, I can easily go back to split these apps back out into dedicated deployments.

What I'm noticing is that when I have two apps that both use `morgan` to do logging, only the second vhost app that is registered produces logger output.

I think I know what's going on but it doesn't hurt to get this clarified.

Since both of the vhosted apps add the logger as a middleware, my guess is that the first app binds it to stdout and so does the second app, so now it's not really clear what happens to the first one, but what is certain is that there's no real mechanism in place for dealing with the situation.

I would expect a way around this would be to just take out the logging from the individual apps and put a single logger in front of the vhost entries (which effectively has turned my full apps into middlewares), that way I can still see all the hits on my server.

However, this would preclude me from being able to do things like not log any requests handled by the static middleware in a particular one of these apps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is going to work, but sometimes making a shared file that is using one morgan instance can be the fix:

```
// logger.js
var morgan = require('morgan')

exports = morgan
```

And require this instead of the morgan by:

```
var morgan = require('./lib/logger')
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Hmmm... seems like trying to smush many apps together is nontrivial when we want to not disturb their logging behavior. I am also finding that using `express.static` also doesn't work...

Comment: I've never used morgan as logger, but used winston instead. I also never had a problem working with multiple winston instances. It always logs to the console..

Comment: Okay I will try that. I also found out why static wasn't working. There are some rather annoying bugs in vhost middleware implementations, which were not too difficult to find.